# Workaround for Xamarin MaskedBehavior jumping cursor issue - 12-digit number with spaces after every four of them

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create an `Entry` for a 12-digit number with spaces after every four digits.

I tried to use `StringFormat` but it doesn't work completely. From what I've read, it works well for Labels that operate on specified texts, not Entries.

I used `MaskedBehavior` from Xamarin Community Toolkit

```
<Entry 
   Margin="25,0,25,0"
   Keyboard="Numeric">
   <Entry.Behaviors>
       <xct:MaskedBehavior Mask="XXXX XXXX XXXX"/>
   </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

but it appears to have an issue with cursor jumping to the end every time when user types something in the middle of an `Entry` or removing a digit from there.
I opened an issue report on XCT GitHub page but haven't received an answer yet:
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1879

[image: Masked Behavior issue]

Since this Mask has an issue, I abandonded this idea for a while and tried to create a `Converter`:

```
public class SerialNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes spaces from the serial number before sending the number further to the code.
    /// </summary>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is string str
            ? str.Replace(" ", "") 
            : null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds spaces to the serial number to display it in a more user-friendly way on the layout.
    /// </summary>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is string str))
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (var i = 4; i <= str.Length; i += 4)
        {
            // edge case: space shouldn't be added once user types in the 12th digit of the serial number
            if (i == 14 && str.Length == 14) break;

            str = str.Insert(i, " ");
            i++;
        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

But it has the same issue.

I tried to operate on `Entry.CursorPosition` in `Converter` and custom `Renderer`, but it behaves weirdly.
It works correctly every **second** time. First time, it does what I want, the second time - it moves to position 0 and then to the end of an `Entry`. Looking at the logs, I can see the event resposible for implying text changed fires twice then, independently of my code.

Did any of you handle this kind of situation? I even checked my bank mobile application and styling of bank account number works well, so it **has to be possible**.

The only idea I have right now is to create a `Grid` with four columns and spacing between them, but that would require creating the whole styling for the control again, so I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: I tested the `MaskedBehavior` of entry in my side and the input of the entry functioned well.So what is your nuget package version for `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit` and `Xamarin.Forms`?  My test environment is CommunityToolkit:2.0.2, Xamarin.Forms:5.0.0.2478, Android 11.

Comment: Hi, I have the same versions as you. What happens when you manually set your cursor position to somewhere in the middle on the input and type something?

Comment: I haven't get a chance to test it.If you have confirmed that it is a potential issue or bug and already posted the issue in Github community, please kindly  follow it in that thread.Thanks!